# Как скачать файл на сервер средствами PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, curl

Вопрос такой, есть вот [такой сайт](http://rasp.rea.ru/Default?GroupName=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87&Teacher=true#day6), на котором есть кнопка "Выгрузить в календарь". По ее нажатию высвечивается модальное окно с кнопкой "Выгрузить". После нажатия на ее скачивается файл.

Вопрос: как скачать его себе средствами PHP? Была идея имитировать нажатия через JS, то что-то не уверен в решении. Также, мне надо поместить этот файл в специальную папку.

Спасибо за подсказки заранее.

Comment: Изучайте как парсить: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Comment: @KirillKorushkin про парсинг такой я знаю. Вопрос заключается больше в том, что при нажатии там что-то происходит и на выходе скачивается файл. Вот его мне как перехватить себе в папку?

Comment: Без непосредственного доступа к сайту никак. Проинспектируйте кнопку в попапе, на ней байндится некая функция. А как она дальше отрабатывает хз. Что за бек у сайта хз. Есть конечно вариант в дев тулс посмотреть куда летит запрос по нажатию на кнопку, а во вкладке source может даже удатся обнаружить функцию-обработчик. Но сделать со всем этим вы ничего не сможете без доступа к сайту. Вот и выходит что спарсить ДОМ страницы и написать свою сохранялку самое оно, имхо.

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку на таких сайтах срабатывает js код, который инициирует ajax-запрос к серверу. Сервер в ответ посылает специальные заголовки загрузки файла и сам файл. Посылает тому, кто инициировал ajax-запрос, т.е. браузеру. На чистом php надо инициировать http-запрос, аналогичный тому, что отправляет браузер, и ждать ответа.